# How do I create a workflow or alert to tell me when a date has past?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, alert

I'm using SharePoint Online and I have a custom list with a date & time column.  I want the system to send me an alert 1 month after the date specified in this column but I don't know how.  Initially, I'd looked at alerts but they don't seem to have that sort of conditioning, I then looked at workflows but I'm a little lost.  Can anyone assist me in creating this alert/workflow control?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply create a **Calculated column (Lets call it Reminder)** = **30 days + Your Date and Time column**

In SharePoint Designer Workflow use List Workflow.

Action : ***Pause till Date*** > Here Use the ***Current Item: Reminder Date*** Filed.

Condition: **If any value equal value:** Current item field (**Current Item: Reminder Date**) is equal to ***Today***

Action : ***Send an Email***

Hope this helps.

Comment: i would rather recommend a microsoft flow than a SP designer pause till date instruction, pause until date is not reliable as it won't capture  changes during the pause or can break during the pause

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) for your scenario.

You can create a [recurring flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/run-scheduled-tasks), which checks the date column in the list and if the condition satisfies it can send the alert via email.

A simple google search on this, and I'm sure you'll achieve what you want.

Comment: As Suggested by Veeraj, I have created Microsoft FLow. But it throws Error for calculated columns. Any help to Create Reminder is much appreciated. Here is the Error:
> { "status": 400, > "message": "The field 'Exam_x0020_1_x0020_Due_x0020_dat' of type 'Calculated' cannot be used in the query filter expression.\r\nclientRequestId ***************" >}

Answer (score 0):

You can make call from any page that you know is hit at least once every day to return all items with a date that equals Today minus 1 month and a flag is not set and if found, send an email and then set the flag so the email is only sent once.  Make your list hidden and give everyone edit access.

Most users should only see a few milliseconds of delay and the unlucky person that actually gets a hit will only see about a 1/2 second delay.  We have our site on a hosted service using old-style workflows (yuk!) and no compiled code is allowed by the provider, so I use our homepage to trigger scripts like a timer job and the users have never noticed a difference.  Certainly not best practice, but it gets the job done...

[I have instructions here on how to send an email in JavaScript](https://grumpyoldsharepointguy.wordpress.com/2017/12/17/how-do-i-send-an-email-in-javascript/).